# how to set Leaflet polyline with two color when set dashArray?

Tags: leaflet, polyline

When create a polyline with Leaflet polyline, and set the dashArray Option with `[12,12]` to dive the line to two part.

Then, how to set the two parts's color.one is use the option `color`, the other one i can't set.

```
var polyline = L.polyline([...], {
    weight: 5,
    dashArray: [12,12],
    color: '#ffffff'
});
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: draw another polyline using the second color (no dash) below the dashed polyline

Comment: xmojmr, thank you, it get worked.